# Good cex-adjusted rotated text labels in R, especially at srt=180

Tags: r, plot, label

I have been struggling with placing rotated text labels how I want them to be, so I finally decided to create a reference plot for quick intution:
[image]

code included below.    This plot illustrates some of the sensitivities with respect to font sizes.

What I have not managed to do is to create a right-justified "Angle is 180" that leaves a modest amount of space to the anchor point.  (You can think of this as keeping the location and rotating the text by 180 degrees.)  For that matter, the 135 angle and 225 degree angles also should be rotated 180 degrees. If someone knows how to do this, I would love to know.

[image: wanted circular text arrangement]

```
iaw$hline <- function (yloc, xloc = c(-9e99,9e99), ...)
  for (i in 1:length(yloc)) lines(xloc, c(yloc[i], yloc[i]), ...)

iaw$vline <- function (xloc, yloc = c(-9e99,9e99), ...) 
  for (i in 1:length(xloc)) lines(c(xloc[i], xloc[i]), yloc, ...)


angles <- (0:5)*45

S <- 150

png(file = "textlabels.png", width = 9 * S, height = 6 * S, pointsize = 24 )
#pdf(file = "textlabels.pdf", width = 9, height = 6, pointsize = 12 )

plot( 0, ylim=c(0,100), xlim=c(0,100), xlab="", ylab="", type="n" )

iaw$vline( c(10,30,40,55,75,95), col="gray", lwd=0.5 )
iaw$hline( c(10,30,60,85), col="gray", lwd=0.5 )

################

x <- 10

y <- 20
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a )
text( x, y - 20, "A. cex=1", cex=0.5, col="blue" )

y <- 60
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3 )
text( x, 5+y - 10, "B. srt=a", cex=0.5, col="blue" )

################

x <- 30

y <- 10
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3, pos=1 )
text( x, y - 10, "C. pos=1", cex=0.5, col="blue" )

y <- 60
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3, pos=2 )
text( x, y - 10, "D. pos=2", cex=0.5, col="blue" )

y <- 30
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3, pos=3 )
text( x, 5+y - 10, "E. pos=3", cex=0.5, col="blue" )

y <- 85
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3, pos=4 )
text( x, y - 10, "F. pos=4", cex=0.5, col="blue" )


x <- 40
y <- 10
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3, adj=c(-2,3), pos=1 )
text( x, y - 10, "G. pos=1\nadj=(-2,3)", cex=0.5, col="blue" )

text( x, 15, "(pos overrides adj)", cex=0.5, col="blue")


################

x <- 55

y <- 30
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3/2, adj=c(-0.5,0.5) )
text( x, 3+y - 10, "H. adj=(-0.5,0.5)\ncex=0.15", cex=0.5, col="blue" )

y <- 10
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3, adj=c(-0.5,0.5) )
text( x, y - 10, "I. adj=(-0.5,+0.5)", cex=0.5, col="blue" )


y <- 60
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3, adj=c(1,0) )
text( 1+x, y - 10, "J. adj=(1,0)", cex=0.5, col="blue" )


y <- 85
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3, adj=c(-0.0,0.0) )
text( x, y - 10, "K. adj=(-0.0,+0.0)", cex=0.5, col="blue" )


################


x <- 75

y <- 10; x <- 85;
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=1.0, adj=c(-0.5,0.5) )
text( 5+ x, y - 5, "L. adj=(-0.5,+0.5)\ncex=1", cex=0.5, col="blue" )
x <- 75


y <- 60
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3, adj=c(1,1) )
text( x, y - 10, "M. adj=(1,1)", cex=0.5, col="blue" )


y <- 85
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3, adj=c(0,1) )
text( x, 3+ y - 10, "N. adj=(0,1)", cex=0.5, col="blue" )


################

rect( 88,47,103,72, border="red" )

x <- 95
y <- 60
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.4, adj=c(-0.25,0.5) )
text( x, y - 10, "O. adj=(-0.25,0.5)", cex=0.5, col="blue" )



y <- 85
points( x, y, col="blue", pch=20 )
for (a in angles) text( x, y, paste0("Angle is ", a), srt=a, cex=0.3, adj=c(-0.5,0.5) )
text( x, y - 10, "P. adj=(-0.5,+0.5)", cex=0.5, col="blue" )

text(55, 38, "Distance between Point and Text\nis Font-Size Dependent", col="blue", cex=0.5)


################

dev.off()
```

Comment: Nice plot - axis labels would help a lot (if the axes are meaningful? Seems like sometimes yes sometimes no, I can't really tell). I'm pretty confused about your goal. The one you've put a red box around looks pretty good to me. Do you not like it? Why?

Comment: And *"the 135 angle and 225 degree angles also should be rotated 180 degrees"* makes no sense to me...

Comment: The red box is the closest to what I like.  However, the labels on the left are upside down from the perspective of the viewer.  so I would like to rotate them without losing the anchor point---now, they will have to be right-justified inside the box rather than left-justified.

Comment: I'm still very confused about what you want. What do you mean by "losing the anchor point"? Maybe you could create what you want with an image editor and post it?

Comment: Thank you, the have/wanted diagram is very clear. Unfortunately, R uses angle strictly for rotation. Your "wanted" angle 180 vs angle 0 has no rotation - the only difference is the justification. I think the only solution will be to handle those separately. But perhaps now that the question is clear someone else will have other ideas.